# "no key matching the described characteristics could be found within the current range"

Tags: sql, .net, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce, sqlcedatareader

I am using SQL CE 4.0 and the following code:

```
string sqlQuery = "SELECT TOP 10 " + 
            "tbl_Image.ImageID, tbl_Barcode.BarcodeValue, tbl_Image.ImageDateTime, tbl_Image.ImageFileName " +
            "FROM " +
            "tbl_Image " +
            "JOIN tbl_Barcode on tbl_Image.ImageID = tbl_Barcode.ImageID " +
            "WHERE " +
            "tbl_Image.ImageID > @ImageID";

        using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(sqlQuery, sqlceServer.GetSqlConnection()))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@ImageID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = imageID;

            try
            {
                using (SqlCeDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Scrollable))
                {
                    if (rdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
```

But I keep getting the error :

"no key matching the described characteristics could be found within the current range"

on this line :

```
using (SqlCeDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Scrollable))
```

I have tried changing this line to various different options to no avail.

My sql ce db is contains two tables created with the following (excerpt):

```
string tblImage =
            "CREATE TABLE [tbl_Image] (" +
            "[ImageID] int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL" +
            ", [ImageData] image NOT NULL" +
            ", [ImageDateTime] datetime NOT NULL" +
            ", [ImageFileName] nvarchar(4000) NOT NULL" +
            ", [SettingID] int NOT NULL" +
            ", [MultiPage] bit NOT NULL" +
            ");";

        string tblBarcode =
            "CREATE TABLE [tbl_Barcode] (" +
              "[BarcodeID] int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL" +
            ", [ImageID] int NOT NULL" +
            ", [BarcodeType] nvarchar(4000) NOT NULL" +
            ", [BarcodeValue] nvarchar(4000) NOT NULL" +
            ");";

        string alterImageTable =
            "ALTER TABLE [tbl_Image] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Image] PRIMARY KEY ([ImageID]);";

        string alterBarcodeTable =
                    "ALTER TABLE [tbl_Barcode] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Barcode] PRIMARY KEY ([BarcodeID]);";
```

I am puzzled as to what the problem is - googling the error seems to refer to replication issues which I am not doing.  Can anyone help please?

EDIT:

Running the query in SQL Server Compact Toolbox v4.0 works no problem and returns the correct data.

Comment: Try changing resultsetoptions to non-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

The top command must have the number in brackets ie TOP (10) and the HasRows command is not supported apparently so removing that line also enables the query to function.